# Picard group of moduli of principal bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, principal-bundles, picard-group

I am looking for the **Picard group of the moduli space of principal $G$-bundles** for a connected reductive complex algebraic group $G$.

Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$? If not, what can we say when $G=\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})?$

Is there any reference for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem A in:

S. Kumar and M. S. Narasimhan. *Picard group of the moduli spaces of G-bundles.* Math. Ann., 308(1):155-173, 1997,

shows that when $G$ is a simple simply-connected connected complex affine algebraic group, $C$ is a complex smooth irreducible projective curve of genus at least 2, and $M$ is the moduli space of semistable principal $G$-bundles on $C$,  then $\mathrm{Pic}(M)\cong \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any specific result when G is not simple?

Comment: I do not know of any references that specifically address the non-simple case.  I suspect that if $G$ is complex, reductive (and connected) then the above result can be used to determine what happens when the derived subgroup $DG$ is simply-connected.  That intuition comes from my paper with C. Manon that does the computation for $G$-character varieties of punctured surfaces: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01210.pdf (corollary 2.4).  But of course that is a different moduli space (although a related one).